# Converting square wave into a sine wave

Tags: frequency, wave, sine, conversion, square

I am trying to convert a 1 MHz square wave into a sine wave of the same frequency. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Is this fixed or variable frequency?

Comment: Best way depends on how much money and time you want or are willing to throw at the problem. Usually you would have some specification how good a sine wave you need and how much distortion is allowed.

Comment: XY problem. *Why* are you trying to do this. *Why* can you not simply generate your 1MHz sine wave in the 1st place.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. The frequency is fixed at 1MHz;

Comment: This Sine Wave generator needs specs for THD, Amplitude and source impedance. Can you think of any with tolerances?

Comment: filter out all the non-1MHz waves.

Comment: Don't try that filter before you define the specs. or acceptance criteria.

Comment: Since "The frequency is fixed at 1MHz" that's even more reason to just generate the sine wave from scratch instead of a square wave. You really need to add more detail to your question to justify why you want to start with a square wave and turn it into a sine wave.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Where is the 1 MHz square wave coming from? Is it straight from an oscillator? Or is it a signalling waveform or otherwise significant? Please edit your question to explain that, as others have asked, it completely changes any answers you get. Thanks and, again, welcome.

Answer (score 6):

But a square wave is already a sine wave. Or to be more precise it is a infinite sum of sine waves. Just feed the output of the square wave to a filter which will cutoff all the unnecessary frequencies and you are good.

Comment: And if you're going to build a nice sharp 1MHz band-pass filter ... you may as well just build a 1MHz sine wave oscillator instead.

Comment: You low pass filter out the frequencies since the main frequency is the lowest from all the harmonics.

Comment: Ok - same thing though - if you're building a filter (no matter if it's low pass or band-pass) that's "sharp" enough to give a nice clean sine wave, then it'll be high-enough order that the number of active components (opamps) required will be more than enough to just build an oscillator instead.

Comment: @brhans often you do have a good clock that's not purely sine – for example, a square wave clock coming out of an OCXO IC package including its own amplifier, or a square wave coming from the back of an expensive measurement device, or out of your GPSDO.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - So if anything like that is the case then the OP needs to fill us in on the details. In those sorts of cases you're probably concerned about things like phase delay or whatever. With the current dearth of details provided, the "best" way IMO is to just generate the sine wave you want directly rather than trying to "convert" a square wave.

Answer (score 2):

Hey use a LC (second order) filter with a high Quality factor. You will achieve a 1MHz sine wave.
Cheeers!!